# Open a TemporaryFile using open()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to interface with an existing library that uses the built in [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function to read a `.json` file using [either a str or bytes object representing a path, or an object implementing the os.PathLike protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-like-object).

My function generate a dictionary which is converted to `json` using `json.dump()`, but I'm not sure how to pass that to the existing function which expects a file path.

I was thinking something like this might work, but I'm not sure how to get a `os.PathLike` object of a TemporaryFile.

```
import tempfile
temp_file = tempfile.TemporaryFile('w')
json.dump('{"test": 1}', fp=temp_file)
file = open(temp_file.path(), 'r')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a [`NamedTemporaryFile()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) instead; it has a `.name` attribute you can pass on to the function:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

with NamedTemporaryFile('w') as jsonfile:
    json.dump('{"test": 1}', jsonfile)
    jsonfile.flush()  # make sure all data is flushed to disk
    # pass the filename to something that expects a string
    open(jsonfile.name, 'r')
```

Opening an already-open file object does have issues on Windows (you are not allowed to); there you'd have to close the file object first (making sure to disable delete-on-close), and delete it manually afterwards:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import os

jsonfile = NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False)
try:
    with jsonfile:
        json.dump('{"test": 1}', jsonfile)
    # pass the filename to something that expects a string
    open(jsonfile.name, 'r')
finally:
    os.unlink(jsonfile.name)
```

The `with` statement causes the file to be closed when the suite exits (so by the time you reach the `open()` call).