# How to upload File in FastAPI, then to Amazon S3 and finally process it?

Tags: python, file, amazon-s3, boto3, fastapi

I have a FastAPI endpoint that receives a file, uploads it to s3, and then processes it. Everything works fine except for the processing, that fails with this message:

```txt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/datastructures.py", line 441, in read
    return self.file.read(size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/tempfile.py", line 735, in read
    return self._file.read(*args)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

My simplified code looks like this:

```python
async def process(file: UploadFile):
    reader = csv.reader(iterdecode(file.file.read(), "utf-8"), dialect="excel")  # This fails!
    datarows = []
    for row in reader:
        datarows.append(row)
    return datarows
```

How can I read the contents of the uploaded file?

**UPDATE**

I managed to isolate the problem a bit more. Here's my simplified endpoint:

```python
import boto3
from loguru import logger
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


UPLOAD = True

@router.post("/")
async def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    if UPLOAD:
        # Upload the file
        s3_client = boto3.client("s3", endpoint_url="http://localstack:4566")
        try:
            s3_client.upload_fileobj(file.file, "local", "myfile.txt")
        except ClientError as e:
            logger.error(e)
    contents = await file.read()
    return JSONResponse({"message": "Success!"})
```

If `UPLOAD` is True, I get the error. If it's not, everything works fine. It seems boto3 is closing the file after uploading it. Is there any way I can reopen the file? Or send a copy to `upload_fileobj`?

Comment: You need to await the content when reading the uploaded file https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/?h=upload#file-parameters-with-uploadfile

Answer (score 16):

FastAPI's (actually Starlette's) [`UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile) (see [Starlette's documentation](https://www.starlette.io/requests/#request-files) as well) uses Python's [`SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile), a "file stored in memory up to a maximum size limit, and after passing this limit it will be stored in disk.". It "operates exactly as [`TemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile)", which "is **destroyed as soon as it is closed** (including an implicit `close` when the object is garbage collected)". Hence, it seems that once the contents of the `file` have been read by `boto3`, the file gets closed, which, in turn, causes the file to be deleted.

### Option 1

If the server supports it, you could read the file contents—using `contents = file.file.read()`, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804) (or for `async` reading/writing see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530))—and then upload these `contents` (i.e.,`bytes`) to your server directly.

Otherwise, you can again read the `contents` and then move the file's reference point at the beginning of the file. In a file there is an internal "cursor" (or "file pointer") denoting the position from which the file contents will be read (or written). When calling `read()` reads all the way to the end of the buffer, leaving zero bytes beyond the cursor. Thus, one could also use the `seek()` method to set the current position of the cursor to `0` (i.e., rewinding the cursor to the start of the file); thus, allowing you to pass the `file` object (i.e., `upload_fileobj(file.file)` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70665801/17865804)) *after* reading the file contents.

As per [FastAPI's documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile):

> `seek(offset)`: Goes to the byte position `offset (int)` in the file.
>
> - E.g., `await myfile.seek(0)` would go to the start of the file.
> - This is especially useful if you run `await myfile.read()` once and then **need to read the contents again**.

##### Example

```py
from fastapi import File, UploadFile, HTTPException

@app.post('/')
def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        contents = file.file.read()
        file.file.seek(0)
        # Upload the file to to your S3 service
        s3_client.upload_fileobj(file.file, 'local', 'myfile.txt')
    except Exception:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail='Something went wrong')
    finally:
        file.file.close()

   print(contents)  # Handle file contents as desired
   return {"filename": file.filename}
```

### Option 2

Copy the contents of the file into a [`NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile), which, unlike [`TemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile), "has a visible name in the file system" that "can be used to open the file" (that name can be retrieved from the `.name` attribute ). Additionally, it **can remain accesible after it is closed**, by setting the `delete` argument to `False`; thus, allowing the file to reopen when needed. Once you are done with it, you can delete it using the `os.remove()` or `os.unlink()` method. Below is a working example (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50240680)):

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, HTTPException
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import os

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/upload")
def upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    try:
        try:
            contents = file.file.read()
            with temp as f:
                f.write(contents);
        except Exception:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail='Error on uploading the file')
        finally:
            file.file.close()
            
        # Upload the file to your S3 service using `temp.name`
        s3_client.upload_file(temp.name, 'local', 'myfile.txt')
        
    except Exception:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail='Something went wrong')
    finally:
        #temp.close()  # the `with` statement above takes care of closing the file
        os.remove(temp.name)  # Delete temp file
    
    print(contents)  # Handle file contents as desired
    return {"filename": file.filename}
```

### Option 3

You could even keep the bytes in an in-memory buffer [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO), use it to upload the contents to the S3 bucket, and finally close it ("*The buffer is discarded when the `close()` method is called*."). Remember to call `seek(0)` method to reset the cursor back to the beginning of the file after you finish writing to the BytesIO stream.

```py
contents = file.file.read()
temp_file = io.BytesIO()
temp_file.write(contents)
temp_file.seek(0)
s3_client.upload_fileobj(temp_file, "local", "myfile.txt")
temp_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

From FastAPI [ImportFile](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#import-file):

Import File and UploadFile from fastapi:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/files/")
async def create_file(file: bytes = File(...)):
    return {"file_size": len(file)}


@app.post("/uploadfile/")
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    return {"filename": file.filename}
```

From FastAPI [UploadFile](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile):

> For example, inside of an async path operation function you can get the
> contents with:

```py
contents = await myfile.read()
```

with your code you should have something like this:

```py
async def process(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    content = await file.read()
    reader = csv.reader(iterdecode(content, "utf-8"), dialect="excel")
    datarows = []
    for row in reader:
        datarows.append(row)
    return datarows
```

Comment: I tried this, but got the same error =/

Comment: Can you add the route you cal land how it interact with your func ? Are you doing a "@app.post" ??

Comment: just added an update ;)