# Upload small file to FastAPI enpoint but UploadFile content is empty

Tags: file-upload, fastapi, starlette

I am trying to upload file (csv) to FastAPI `POST` endpoint.

This is the server code:

```py
@app.post("/csv/file/preview")
async def post_csv_file_preview(file: UploadFile):
    """

    :param file:
    :return:
    """
    contents = file.file.read()
    print(contents)
```

But contents is empty if the file is small. If I increase the file content (add new lines in the csv file), without any others changes, it is working.

If I directly get the request body, the file content is returned normally.

```py
print(await request.body())
```

The problem is only with my production server, not localally:

```bash
PYTHONPATH=/var/www/api/current /var/www/api/current/venv/bin/python /var/www/api/current/venv/bin/uvicorn main:app --reload --port=8004
```

I dont understand

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Upload File using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048825/how-to-upload-file-using-fastapi)

Comment: Also, please make sure that you haven't already read the file contents, before calling `file.file.read()`. If so, you need  to use the `.seek()` method to set the current position of the cursor to `0` (i.e., rewind the cursor to the start of the file), as described in Option 1 of  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70653605/17865804).

Comment: No. I send my file with Insomnia for test in production

Comment: Also, I would not recommend using `async def` endpoint while reading the file contents in a `sync` way. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more details.

Comment: Hoo yes it's ok with seek. Thanks. But is so curious. This file is read only once by request.

Comment: I've encountered the same exact problem: file is only read once, `seek(0)` helps, and it can only be reproduced on production. I've narrowed down "small file" size to 9828 bytes - everything above that reads OK on the first try. Still no idea what causes this, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from Chris, I solved my problem by adding the `.seek()` method before reading the file contents.

```py
@app.post("/csv/file/preview")
def post_csv_file_preview(file: UploadFile):
    """

    :param file:
    :return:
    """
    file.file.seek(0)
    contents = file.file.read()
    print(contents)
```